# dhall-to-yaml: representing unstructured blocks nested within structured yaml

Tags: yaml, dhall

I'm playing around with dhall, trying to represent an existing large yaml file I have instead in dhall.

Specifically, I'm trying to build dhall types and helpers for a concourse pipeline definition. Part of the yaml that defines a concourse pipeline looks like the yaml I've written here. Each resource in my list contains a name, a type and then a source whose structure depends entirely on the type of the resource.

There is no exhaustive list of resources for me to define since someone could create a new one tomorrow and I wouldn't want to update my types each time some third party creates a new source type.

The dhall I have for this is witten here too, but I'm unsure how I could represent `source`. I had considered omitting this field from my type and instructing consumers to use dhall's `//` operator to add a source, but then it becomes difficult to embed `resource`s in a `[resource]` and still have type checking.

How can I define a dhall type for resource that contains within it a field whose value is unstructured.

```
resources:
- name: my-repo
  type: git
  source:
    $some_unstructured_yaml
```

```
{ name   : Text
, type   : Text
, source : Optional ???
}
```

Comment: Your YAML is invalid. Your final sentence should be changed to a direct question (i.e. one about how to solve your problem, not if someone exists that can solve your problem).

Comment: Changed the last sentence to a direct question. The yaml is literally wrong sure, but that's because I'm trying to convey that source could be anything. I'll use notation other than {} to be clearer

Comment: You might want to checkout the Map in the dhall Prelude or perhaps the JSON types, also in the Prelude

Answer (score 3):

This will be possible in the next release (version 1.3.1) of `dhall-json`.

For example, given this schema:

```
-- This will become: https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/JSON/Type
let JSON = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/40c3e57a4f09448b5a7c9d203a81b64f50ed30bd/Prelude/JSON/Type

in  { name   : Text
    , type   : Text
    , source : Optional JSON
    }
```

... and this YAML configuration:

```
name: my-repo
type: git
source:
  foo:
  - 1
  - bar: true
  baz: null
```

... it will produce this Dhall expression:

```
$ yaml-to-dhall ./schema.dhall < example.yml
{ name =
    "my-repo"
, source =
    Some
    (   λ(JSON : Type)
      → λ ( json
          : { array :
                List JSON → JSON
            , bool :
                Bool → JSON
            , null :
                JSON
            , number :
                Double → JSON
            , object :
                List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : JSON } → JSON
            , string :
                Text → JSON
            }
          )
      → json.object
        [ { mapKey =
              "foo"
          , mapValue =
              json.array
              [ json.number 1.0
              , json.object [ { mapKey = "bar", mapValue = json.bool True } ]
              ]
          }
        , { mapKey = "baz", mapValue = json.null }
        ]
    )
, type =
    "git"
}
```

For more details, see the following change to the standard:

- [Prelude: Add standard representation for weakly-typed JSON values](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/pull/586)

... and the following change to the `dhall-json` package:

- [Add `dhall-json` support for weakly-typed JSON values](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-haskell/pull/1007)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I just tried this out and it solves my problem.